# JSoup select numbers

Tags: image, jsoup

```
<div class="sResMain">
    <b>
        <a href="/dogukan1905?&amp;from=search&amp;qs=age1%3D16%26age2%3D27%26sex%255B0%255D%3DMALE%26sex%255B1%255D%3DFEMALE%26region%3D%26keywords%3D%26photo%3D1%26sort%3Dlast_login%26todo%3Dsearch%26offset%3D0" class="male">dogukan1905</a>
    </b>
    <img src="http://eu.ipstatic.net/images/male.gif" width="11" height="11" class="sResSex">
    20 
    <br>
<div class="sResMainTxt">
<div class="sResTxtField">I&nbsp; study at aircraft technology...</div></div></div>
```

I want to select number(20) between `img` and `br` tag. However I couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you posted, the text that you are trying to parse belongs to `<div class="sResMain">`. Moreover this is the only text that `<div class="sResMain">` has. There is a method in Jsoup that will return the text that belongs (immediate textnode child) to a node. Try `ownText()` of `Element`.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlStr);
Elements elements = doc.select(".sResMain");
for(Element e : elements) {
    String text = e.ownText();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```